# Distributing a android library (aar) to consumers : But the source code is in GitHub private repo

Tags: android, maven, github, bintray

I have an android library published in Bintray. The source code is in Github (public) repo.
Consumers just add the dependency in their gradle file and alls good so far.

Now, However, I want to make the GitHub repo private (for some valid reason).
What should I do to let my existing consumers continue to have access to the library in Bintray?

Its Ok if my library is not visible on Internet - I have other channels for potential consumers to get in touch with me if they are interested in my library. Please suggest.

Comment: Need help on this please.

Comment: If it is connected to JCenter then you must have a public repository. You can also upload the `arr` files, and just them, to your Bintray organization maven repository.

Comment: Do you want to make the `arr` files hidden/private or just the source code?

Comment: @Royg: I am facing the same issue, I want to make source code private but aar public or private can't matter... How to achieve this?

Comment: @Nikhil, you can open a Bintray account with a maven repository, then upload to that repository your artifacts. There are manuals on how to build from user owned repositories in Bintray.